# Cannot get ardour to run correctly

Tags: 18.04, gtk, ardour

I installed ardour using `sudo apt install ardour`. When I tried to run ardour from the GUI, nothing happened, so I tried to run it from the terminal (simply typed `ardour`) and I got this output:

```
bind txt domain [gtk2_ardour5] to /opt/ardour/share/locale
Ardour5.12.0 (built using 5.12 and GCC version 5.2.1 20150903)
ardour: [INFO]: Your system is configured to limit Ardour to only 4096 open files
ardour: [INFO]: Loading system configuration file /opt/ardour/etc/system_config
ardour: [INFO]: CPU vendor: AuthenticAMD
ardour: [INFO]: AVX-capable processor
ardour: [INFO]: CPU brand: AMD FX(tm)-6300 Six-Core Processor             
ardour: [INFO]: Using SSE optimized routines
Cannot xinstall SIGPIPE error handler
ardour: [INFO]: Loading default ui configuration file /opt/ardour/etc/default_ui_config

(ardour-5.12.0:3323): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(ardour-5.12.0:3323): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(ardour-5.12.0:3323): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(ardour-5.12.0:3323): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(ardour-5.12.0:3323): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(ardour-5.12.0:3323): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(ardour-5.12.0:3323): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(ardour-5.12.0:3323): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(ardour-5.12.0:3323): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(ardour-5.12.0:3323): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(ardour-5.12.0:3323): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(ardour-5.12.0:3323): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",

(ardour-5.12.0:3323): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
Color shuttle bg not found
ardour: [INFO]: Loading color file /opt/ardour/share/themes/dark-ardour.colors

(ardour-5.12.0:3323): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(ardour-5.12.0:3323): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "adwaita",

(ardour-5.12.0:3323): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",
...
```

The unable to locate theme engine messages that trail at the end continue to appear really fast until I stop it with ctrl-c, with most of them saying "murine", but some still say "adwaita". Due to where it says `Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"`, I tried `sudo apt install libcanberra-gtk-module`, to which it said I already have the newest version. At this point, I have no idea what to do to get it to run correctly, so how can I get it to run correctly?

Comment: Have you installed libcanberra-gtk3-module also ?

Comment: Just tried it and just like libcanberra-gtk-module, it says that I already have the newest version.

Comment: From the information you provided , it seems that there's no problem . Please consider [compile it from source](https://ardour.org/building_linux.html) and install it so see if it gets solved. It might be a bug within that version itself.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have another ardour installed  in /opt  ? Normally, Ardour files are in /usr/share/ardour5 when installed with apt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advice you to just visit `ardor` website [here](https://manual.ardour.org/setting-up-your-system/platform-specifics/ubuntu-linux/) for detail. It said:

> There may be unintended differences, and even bugs in Ubuntu native
>   packages, as a result of a different building method. For this reason,
>   Ardour developers highly recommend installing the official
>   ready-to-run version of the program that can be downloaded from
>   ardour.org, as Ubuntu native packages are not supported in the
>   official Ardour forums or other support channels.
>
> Follow these steps to install the latest version of Ardour:
>
> Download the latest release from ardour.org.
>   Right-click the downloaded file and choose properties.
>   Click the Permissions tab and check the option "Allow this file to run as a program".
>   Close the dialog and double-click the file.
>   Follow the prompts.

So download a ready-to-run program from [here](https://community.ardour.org/download) and follow recommended steps.

Comment: @a-useless-dragon Please confirm if it works for you.